# firebase "clang: error: linker command failed" with ios and xcode

Tags: ios, firebase

Trying to use firebase with iOS and never dealt with pods before

1) I create a project in ios with swift for iPhone.. called stupid
2) Here is where the project is located and the files created:

```
~/Documents/swift/stupid$ ls
stupid          stupid.xcodeproj
```

3) This is what firebase says to do:

```
Move the GoogleService-Info.plist file you just downloaded into the root of your Xcode project and add it to all targets.

~/Documents/swift/stupid/stupid$ ls
AppDelegate.swift       GoogleService-Info.plist    stupid.xcdatamodeld
Assets.xcassets         Info.plist
Base.lproj          ViewController.swift
```

4) I run the below in the ~/Documents/swift/stupid dir
     ~/Documents/swift/stupid$ pod init

```
Google services use CocoaPods to install and manage dependencies. Open a terminal window and navigate to the location of the Xcode project for your app.

Create a Podfile if you don't have one:

pod init
Open your Podfile and add:

pod 'Firebase/Core'
includes Analytics by default help_outline
Save the file and run:

pod install
```

5) I build the project

And now I get this error. Who can tell me why?

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check that you open workspace instead of xcodeproj.